# When changing view controllers, new controller appears, but disappears almost immediately

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code in one of my IBAction (when a button is pressed), which is supposed to bring up a new view controller.

```
let addAlertVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addAlert")

self.present(addAlertVC!, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

However, when I run the app and press the button that's supposed to take me to the new `viewcontroller`, but then I'm stuck with the original `viewcontroller`. I have put a print statement in the `viewDidAppear` function in the new view controller, and it is printing out whenever I press the button, so the new controller is definitely appearing. I have not dismissed the new controller anywhere in my app.

I have used the same code in other parts of my app, so I'm extremely confused as to why it's not working this time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I fixed my code. It turns out it wasn't how I was calling the view controller that was wrong, it was my button. Once I deleted and re-added the button, my code now works.

Comment: Didn't get what you try to do after new VC loads ?

Comment: The new VC just flashes, so I wasn't sure if I was loading the VC correctly or not. So I added a print statement (print("Something happened") to be exact) when the new VC appears.

Comment: Here you need to add your storyboard screenshot so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that your view controller is deallocated after you present it.

Try to declare your view controller outside of the function, in your controller. Something like:

```
class ViewController{

    var addAlertVC:UIViewController?

    ...

    func someFunction(){
        addAlertVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addAlert")

        self.present(addAlertVC!, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```